# How to call prop function with an argument

Tags: reactjs

> I can not access to the age when clicking on the button! I get the alert but not the age. Got something like 'His age is [object Object]'.Thank you!

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( < div >
                <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.props.handleAge}>Click
                </button>
             < /div >
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

        alertAge (age) { 
        alert('His age is ' + age);
    }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
         <Hello  name="Eric" age={25} handleAge={this.alertAge}/ >              
         <Hello name="Dyna" age={30} handleAge={this.alertAge}/ >
         <Hello name="Boss" age={8} handleAge={this.alertAge}/ >

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not being called with the argument you expect, on your Hello component change:

```
<button onClick={() => {this.props.handleAge(this.props.age)}}>Click</button>
```

You need to wrap it and pass the variables you need.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a variable to the `alertAge` function.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => { this.props.handleAge(this.props.age) }}>
                Click
            </button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```